# Abelian approximation of fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, fields

Given a field extension $K/k$ of finite degree and a norm $d$ on $\overline{k}$, what is the smallest real number $\alpha_{d}^K$ such that for every element $z$ of $K$ there is an element $z^a$ of $k^a$, the maximum abelian extension of $k$, such that $d(z - z^a) \leq \alpha_{d}^K$?

For an element $z$ of $K$, call the elements of $k^a$ that are closest to it in the above sense "$d$-abelian cousins" of $z$. Suppose $K_d^a$ is the abelian extension of $k$ generated by $d$-abelian cousins of all the elements of $K$. How are the invariants - numerical and Galois-theoretic - of $K$ related to those of $K_d^a$, the "$d$-abelian cousin of $K$"?

The primary fields of interest to me are number fields and $p$-adic fields with their usual norms.

Comment: What sort of compatibility, if any, do you require between the metric and the field?  I don't know many fields with interesting metrics.

Comment: @LSpice, I have expressed it in terms of field norms. Hope that clarifies what I had in mind.